# Download zip file from ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, anaconda, arcgis-python-api, pyscripter

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
import sys
import urllib.request as req
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
import os
import trace
import urllib.request as req

Zip_Loc = r'C:\Folder'
data_item_id = 'someId'


def downloadData():
    gisx = GIS("https://xyz.123.arcgis.com", username='12344353', password='abcdef',proxy_host='***.***.***.**',proxy_port=****)

    data_item = gisx.content.get(data_item_id )
    data_path = Path(Zip_Loc)

    zipPath = data_path.joinpath('Data.zip')
    data_item.download(save_path=data_path)

def main():
    downloadData()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The error I get is

> urllib.error.URLError:
>
> OSError: Tunnel connection failed: 407 authenticationrequired

I'm geting error in data_item.download....... line

I already passed proxy in GIS line, and I can download normally in browser.

This data_item_id is secured one and this user got access, do I need to generate token and download?

Comment: Is this on `arcgis.com` or your own local portal? If arcgis.com, just use `http://www.arcgis.com`, dont put your Org name into the URL.

Comment: @khibma it’s from my org url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had it worked by changing proxy format

proxy_host='windowsuser:password@proxy'